# segmentation fault with deep copy

Tags: c++, constructor, copy, copy-on-write

I am trying to make a deep copy (for copy on write) of an object but I get a segmentation fault.

I am using a hashtable with linked list.

```
    class Person
{
public:
    Person(const char * id,int nb)
    {
        this->id=strdup(id);
        this->nb=nb;
        this->init=init;
        this->next=NULL;
    }
    Person(const Person& rhs) :
    nb(rhs.nb),
    init(rhs.init),
    id(strdup(rhs.id)),
    next(rhs.next == NULL ? NULL : new Person(*rhs.next)) {}

    char* strdup(char const* in)
    {
        char* ret = new char[strlen(in)+1];
        strcpy(ret, in);
        return ret;
    }

    int nb,init;
    const char * id;
    Person *next;
};


    Hashtable deepcopy (const Hashtable& rhs)
    {
    num[0]=num[0]-1;
    Person** array=rhs.table;
    Hashtable autre;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < size; ++i)
        if (autre.table[i]!=NULL)
            autre.table[i] = new Person(*array[i]);
    return autre;
    num[0]=1;
}
```

the attributs of my class Hashtable:

```
 Person **table;
    int* num;
```

**EDIT: this problem seem to be fixed.**
What is wrong with my deep copy? I don't understand. I think that my copy constructor is good but I don't understand why I get a seg fault when I run it.

Comment: I've removed "cpp" from the question title. First, the language is called C++; "cpp" commonly refers to the C preprocessor. Second, the question is tagged "c++, so there's no need to specify the language in the title.

Comment: Why in the world are you using dynamic allocation for a single int (or, really, at all)?  Where is `size` coming from?  Also, `std::copy`

Comment: I am trying to implement copy on write for my hashtable. The size is defined and equal to 300. I cannot use std. I can use: #include cstdio, cstdlib, cstring, iostream.

Comment: @bandera Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40164/should-we-close-fix-my-program-questions

Answer (score 1):

This code must be fixed:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < size; ++i)
    autre.table[i] = new Person(*array[i]);
```

`table` has fixed size, and it's filled with null-pointers. In your loop, you don't check if the element to be copied is a null-pointer, so you derefence it and try to copy the entity which even doesn't exist.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < size; ++i) {
    if(array[i] != NULL) {
        autre.table[i] = new Person(*array[i]);
    }
}
```

PS: It's better to use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Problems that I see:

1. Default constructor of `Person`.

   ```
   Person(const char * id,int nb)
   {
     this->id=id;
     this->next=NULL;
   }
   ```

   If I use

   ```
   Person foo()
   {
     char id[] = "John";
     return Person(id, 0);
   }

   Person a = foo();
   ```

   Then the stack memory used for holding "John" in `foo` is now held on to by `a`, which will lead to undefined behavior.

   You need to take ownership of the input string. Use `std::string` for `id` instead of `char const*`.
2. Copy constructor of `Person`.

   The statement

   ```
   id(rhs.id),
   ```

   will be a problem if you decide to use `char const*` as type for `id`. If you switch it to `std::string`, it won't be a problem.
3. Copy constructor of `HashTable` makes a shallow copy of `table`. This will be a problem if you decide to delete the `table` in the destructor of `HashTable`. If you don't delete `table` in the destructor of `HashTable`, you have a memory leak.
4. In `deepcopy`, you are not checking whether `array[i]` is NULL before dereferencing it. This has already been pointed out by @alphashooter. Additionally, you are creating a deep copy in a local variable of the function,`autre`. The deep copy is not visible outside the function unless you return `autre` from it.

**EDIT**
Since you are not allowed, to use `std::string`, you will have to allocate memory for the `char const*` in the default constructor as well as the copy constructor. If your platform has the non-standard function `strdup` and you are allowed to use it, you can change the default constructor to:

```
Person(const char * id,int nb)
{
  this->id=strdup(id);
  this->next=NULL;
}
```

You need to make a similar change to the copy constructor.

If you don't have `strdup` or you are not allowed to use it, you can define it. It's a very simple function to write.

```
char* strdup(char const* in)
{
  char* ret = new char[strlen(in)+1];
  strcpy(ret, in);
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. 1) It is a part of an exercise and I cannot use std::string. How can I fix it? 2) I cannot use std string unfortunately. 3) I am trying to implement copy-on-write. I create a shallow copy and make it deep when I want to modify something. 4) Thank you, I now return autre in the function.

Comment: @bandera I updated my answer to explain what you can do if you are not allowed to use `std::string`.

Comment: "*Then temporary memory used for holding "John" is held on to by a*" What?! "John" is a constant. The temporary holds a pointer to the constant, but he saves a copy of that pointer, so it doesn't matter if it goes away.

Comment: Thanks, no segmentation fault anymore but now the insertion is not working after a deep copy. I edited my post.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Perhaps my understanding of what compilers/run time environments do with constants like "John" is flawed. I need a better example of why holding on the input `char const*` will lead to undefined behavior.